# Problems making a script to draw a line from MatLab to AutoCAD

Tags: matlab, scripting, autocad, cad

I want to make a project where I can draw an electric motor using data calculated in MatLab. I know how to do draw it in  AutoCAD, and now I want to make this implementation with MatLab.

I started to learn how to draw MatLab calculations in AutoCAD, but I have a few errors in the script and I can't understand what is wrong.
First of all, I'm using ActiveX to make the connection. The connection is working, I managed to make it. The problem is when I try to draw a line

```
feature('COM_SafeArraySingleDim', 1)
acad=actxGetRunningServer('AutoCAD.Application');
set(acad,'visible',1);
c_doc=get(acad,'ActiveDocument');
dwg=c_doc.PaperSpace;


a=[1;5];
b=[3;4];

invoke(dwg,'AddLine',a,b);
```

The main error is Description: Incorrect number of elements in SafeArray. I used the 2D space of work(PaperSpace), but if I'm adding a third value in a and b, the script works, but no lines are drawn.

If you think this is not the best solution to pick for working on a project like this, can you recommend me some books, youtube videos or some sources from where I can learn?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The ActiveX [`AddLine`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2020/ENU/?guid=GUID-26C95029-14BB-40B9-9987-49EFC980CB9D) method requires the start & end point arguments to be 3D points expressed relative to the World Coordinate System (WCS) and represented by (safe)arrays of 3 doubles.

As such, your arrays will need to contain three numerical values, e.g.:

```
a=[1.0;5.0;0.0];
b=[3.0;4.0;0.0];

invoke(dwg,'AddLine',a,b);
```

Is there any reason that you are creating your lines in Paperspace?

As the name implies, Paperspace would typically be used for titleblocks and annotation, with a viewport displaying the relevant geometry defined in Modelspace.

You may also need to regenerate the drawing to cause the lines to be drawn, which may look something like this:

```
invoke(c_doc,'Regen',0);
```